# C#: Is it possible to create a bitmap from a resource image in program.cs?

Tags: c#, bitmap

In my application, I want to create a bitmap to draw on, and then show it on more than one form.  I need to coordinate the update of the bitmap centrally, so I wanted to do that from MAIN based on a timer.  The bitmap is to be re-sized to the full size of the screen upon creation.  Is it this attempt to resize that is causing the exception ?

The code looks fine, and VS doesn't complain until I try to debug, and then it throws a "Parameter is not valid' exception on the line where the bitmap is created.

I have selectively compressed my code below:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Timers;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Reflection;

namespace MyProgram
{
  /// <summary>
  /// Class with program entry point.
  /// </summary>
  internal sealed class Program
  {
    /// <summary>
    /// Program entry point.
    /// </summary>
    /// 

    public struct Config {
        public int Guns;
        public int RedGunMin;
        public int RedGunMax;
        public int X;
        public int Y;
        public double PointRatio;
    }

    public static Config TC;

    public static int OffsetX = 0;
    public static int OffsetY = 0;
    public static int Offset = 0;
    public static int FirstPass = 0;

    public static int XC = 0;
    public static int YC = 0;

    public static int RedVal = 0;
    public static int GreenVal = 0;
    public static int BlueVal = 0;

    //Set up the random number seed
    public static Random rand = new Random();

    //Create a bitmap object (from the image in the resource file)
    //***** The following line of code (70) generates the error: *****
    public static System.Drawing.Bitmap myBitMap = new Bitmap(MyProgram.Resource1.Black600x600,Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.X, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Y);

    private static System.Timers.Timer myTimer;

    [STAThread]
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);


        if (args.Length > 0)
        {
            string firstArgument = args[0].ToLower().Trim();

            if (firstArgument == "/c")           // Configuration mode
            {
                // TODO
            }
            else //(firstArgument == "/s")      Full-screen mode, and default mode
            {
                //Read the config file
                string strDocFolder;
                TileConfig TC = new TileConfig();

                strDocFolder = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);

                //Check to see if the INI file exists
                if (File.Exists(strDocFolder + "\\TileConfig.ini"))
                {
                    //Read the configuration out of the file
                    TextReader TR = new StreamReader(strDocFolder + "\\TileConfig.ini");

                    TC.Guns = Convert.ToInt32(TR.ReadLine());
                    TC.RedGunMin = Convert.ToInt32(TR.ReadLine());
                    TC.RedGunMax = Convert.ToInt32(TR.ReadLine());
                    TC.X = Convert.ToInt32(TR.ReadLine());
                    TC.Y = Convert.ToInt32(TR.ReadLine());
                    TC.PointRatio = Convert.ToDouble(TR.ReadLine());

                    TR.Dispose();
                }
                else
                {
                    //File does not exist, assign default values
                    TC.Guns = 3;
                    TC.RedGunMin = 0;
                    TC.RedGunMax = 255;
                    TC.X = 4;
                    TC.Y = 3;
                    TC.PointRatio = 0.10;
                }

                //Choose initial color
                RedVal = rand.Next(0, 255);

                ShowScreen();

                myTimer.Start();

                Application.Run();
            }
        }

    }
```

When I copy the exception detail to the clipboard this is what I get:

```
System.TypeInitializationException was unhandled
 HResult=-2146233036
 Message=The type initializer for 'MyProgram.Program' threw an exception.
 Source=MyProgram
 TypeName=MyProgram.Program
 StackTrace:
      at MyProgram.Program.Main(String[] args)
      at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
      at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
      at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
      at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
      at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
      at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
      at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
InnerException: System.ArgumentException
     HResult=-2147024809
     Message=Parameter is not valid.
     Source=System.Drawing
     StackTrace:
          at System.Drawing.Bitmap..ctor(Int32 width, Int32 height, PixelFormat format)
          at System.Drawing.Bitmap..ctor(Image original, Int32 width, Int32 height)
          at MyProgram.Program..cctor() in C:\Users\Randy\Documents\SharpDevelop Projects\MyProgram\MyProgram\Program.cs:line 70
   InnerException:
```

Thank you for any assistance you can provide.  You guys are the greatest and I really appreciate the way you all help folks out !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exception detail clearly indicates that you are calling a `Bitmap` constructor that expects `width` and `height`, while you are passing  coordinates - `Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.X` and `Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Y`, which most probably are 0, hence a non valid size.

If your intention is to create a bitmap with screen size, use `Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width` and `Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height` instead. Or the [overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0wh0045z(v=vs.110).aspx) that accepts `Size` and pass `Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Size`.

Comment: Thank you for your quick help !  And for your patience with an old hacker who often reads his own meanings into parameters instead of reading the documentation thoroughly !